# Represent walls in a adjacency list

Tags: algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm, maze

```
1111111111
1111110101
1100010101
1111011101
1001010001
1111010101
1100010101
1111011101
1001000001
1111111111
1=Wall
0=Path
```

Hello i am wondering if i need to add into my adjacency list, wall nodes if i can determine whether a node is a wall through its property, Because since from my knowledge walls will not be considered in calculating the cost for finding a shortest path from a source to a target, for example using A* algorithm.

also Assuming i have a lists of Node objects and each node object contains a list of adjacent nodes, do i need to store adjacent wall nodes?

Comment: I suggest trying it without storing adjacent wall nodes, and seeing if it works.

Comment: If you don't plan on using the wall node information, then you do not need to store the wall node information. It's up to you to decide if you are going to use it or not.

Comment: Hello, dont i need the wall information to determine whether a path is a wall or not so i dont end up walking inside a wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is hard to say anything for sure without knowing more details, but for most of the shortest path search algorithms it is fine not to create any nodes for cells that contain a wall at all.